# Fresnel Rhomb Retarder specifications

Tags: geometric-optics, design

In my homework I have a [Fresnel rhomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_rhomb) retarder and I am asked to calculate the retardance. I have the refractive index in terms of the wavelength(dispersion equation) and the phase difference incurred upon TE and TM polarized waves upon TIR. I only miss the angle and by looking at the product data sheet from [this site](https://www.thorlabs.com/NewGroupPage9.cfm?ObjectGroup_ID=154) (Thor Labs) I was unable to figure out the angle of incidence at the surfaces of the prism. Can anyone give me a hint on this?
The drawing for the prism can be found below for anyone who is interested.
[image]

Comment: I think conventionally these are used with normal incidence - that certainly seems to be implied by the first diagram in the wiki link you include in your question.

Comment: @Floris I think that also but I am not able to calculate the angle of incidence at the two faces of the prism where total internal reflection occurs, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Thor Labs link, and clicking on the "drawings" tab, I see the following diagram:

[image]

I think I can conclude that the height of one (reflecting) side of the rhomb is 16 mm, and the run distance is (36.1 - 9.5)=26.6 mm. This would make the angle $\tan^{-1}\frac{16}{26.6}=31.0˚$. The angle of incidence is then $90-31.0=59.0˚$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did not understand how you inferred that the reflecting side of the rhomb is 16 mm just from the beam displacement?

Comment: I am _assuming_ that the rhomb is designed so that a centered beam in == centered beam out. The dimension we really need isn't explicitly given; that's why I said "I _think_ I can conclude...". Making reasonable assumptions is often necessary to make progress.

Comment: Okay I understood now, by the way can we say that if the prism is rhomboid the beam displacement will always be equal to the difference in height of the two surfaces where the beam go in and go out.

Comment: That is not necessarily true, although it makes sense to design the rhomboid that way - because that's how you ensure that a beam that enters at any point at the entrance face can exit at a corresponding point at the exit face. So it's true for a "good" design, but not a given.

Comment: The angle turned out to be 55° +/- 33 arcseconds, Thoblabs representative provided another drawing for the prism too. Thanks for your help once again.

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of this. Did the rep explain where our calculation was wrong - or was it just the drawing for a different prism...?

Comment: Actually I had sent the e-mail before performing any calculations; therefore he did not see the calculations. The assumption that the beam exits at a corresponding point on the exit face was wrong then.